# How to solve the problem that many thread blocked in org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader#loadClass

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, hazelcast, spring-cache

I find most thread is block in org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader#loadClass, when run a stress test on a api base in the spring boot project.The infomation of the project like following:

> Web server: embed tomcat 9.0.31;
>
> Framework: spring boot 2.1.4.RELEASE;
>
> Cache: hazelcast 3.11.2;

Following is the embed tomcat config in yml file:

```
server:
  port: 8081
  tomcat:
    max-threads: 300
    min-spare-threads: 50
```

Only 31 thread status is RUNNABLE, But 287 thread status is BLOCKED.The BLOCKED thread all blocked in the same lock, and only one thread get the lock.

The java code is:

```
@CacheConfig(cacheNames = CacheConstants.CACHE_CHANNEL_TVCOLUMN)
@Slf4j
@Service
public class ChannelTvColumnServiceImpl implements ChannelTvColumnService {

    @Autowired
    private ChannelTvColumnMapper channelTvColumnMapper;

    @Override
    @Cacheable(key = "T(String).valueOf(#channelPk)")
    public long findTvColumnPkByChanelPk(long channelPk) {
        ChannelTvColumnEntity entity = channelTvColumnMapper.findByChanelPk(channelPk);
        if (entity != null) {
            return entity.getTvColumnPk();
        }
        return 0;
    }

    @CacheEvict(allEntries = true)
    @Override
    public void removeChannelTvColumnMappingCache() {
    }
}
```

The 287 BLOCK thread all waiting to the same lock <0x000000070312c2b0>, the stack strace is:

```
"http-nio-8081-exec-352" #496 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007ff51c237000 nid=0x5c6f waiting for monitor entry [0x00007ff4e9c42000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader.loadClass(TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader.java:66)
        - waiting to lock <0x000000070312c2b0> (a java.lang.Object)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1188)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
        at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:275)
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.support.StandardTypeLocator.findType(StandardTypeLocator.java:103)
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ExpressionState.findType(ExpressionState.java:155)
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.TypeReference.getValueInternal(TypeReference.java:69)
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueRef(CompoundExpression.java:53)
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:89)
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:109)
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:265)
        at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheOperationExpressionEvaluator.key(CacheOperationExpressionEvaluator.java:104)
        at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport$CacheOperationContext.generateKey(CacheAspectSupport.java:778)
        at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.generateKey(CacheAspectSupport.java:575)
        at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.findCachedItem(CacheAspectSupport.java:518)
        at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:401)
        at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:345)
        at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor.invoke(CacheInterceptor.java:61)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)
        at cn.xxx.xxx.channel.service.impl.ChannelTvColumnServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ed4e124b.findTvColumnPkByChanelPk(<generated>)
        at cn.xxx.xxx.news.controller.v1.ChannelNewsController.getChannelNews(ChannelNewsController.java:69)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor231.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:189)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:892)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at cn.xxx.xxx.apiauth.filter.ApiAuthFilter.doFilter(ApiAuthFilter.java:124)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:96)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:688)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1639)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        - locked <0x00000006fac89ee8> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - <0x00000007053bd608> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)
```

The thread stack trace that own the lock is:

```
"http-nio-8081-exec-47" #160 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007ff5a56f8000 nid=0x53cd runnable [0x00007ff4fcf48000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.lang.Throwable.fillInStackTrace(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Throwable.fillInStackTrace(Throwable.java:783)
        - locked <0x00000006c6945770> (a java.lang.ClassNotFoundException)
        at java.lang.Throwable.<init>(Throwable.java:287)
        at java.lang.Exception.<init>(Exception.java:84)
        at java.lang.ReflectiveOperationException.<init>(ReflectiveOperationException.java:75)
        at java.lang.ClassNotFoundException.<init>(ClassNotFoundException.java:82)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        - locked <0x000000070370a870> (a java.lang.Object)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:411)
        - locked <0x000000070312cfb8> (a java.lang.Object)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:93)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader.loadFromParent(TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader.java:112)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader.doLoadClass(TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader.java:85)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader.loadClass(TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader.java:68)
        - locked <0x000000070312c2b0> (a java.lang.Object)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1188)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
        at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:275)
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.support.StandardTypeLocator.findType(StandardTypeLocator.java:103)
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ExpressionState.findType(ExpressionState.java:155)
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.TypeReference.getValueInternal(TypeReference.java:69)
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueRef(CompoundExpression.java:53)
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:89)
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:109)
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:265)
        at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheOperationExpressionEvaluator.key(CacheOperationExpressionEvaluator.java:104)
        at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport$CacheOperationContext.generateKey(CacheAspectSupport.java:778)
        at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.generateKey(CacheAspectSupport.java:575)
        at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.findCachedItem(CacheAspectSupport.java:518)
        at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:401)
        at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:345)
        at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor.invoke(CacheInterceptor.java:61)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)
        at cn.xxx.xxx.channel.service.impl.ChannelTvColumnServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ed4e124b.findTvColumnPkByChanelPk(<generated>)
        at cn.xxx.xxx.news.controller.v1.ChannelNewsController.getChannelNews(ChannelNewsController.java:69)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor231.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:189)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:892)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at cn.xxx.xxx.apiauth.filter.ApiAuthFilter.doFilter(ApiAuthFilter.java:124)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:96)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:688)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1639)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        - locked <0x00000006fac0ac98> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - <0x0000000703181010> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)
```

the analyze of the jvm thread like following picture:
[analyze of the jvm thread stack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IetEk.png)

According the thread stack, I find the function `org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.TypeReference#getValueInternal` would be called, and the function source code in following:

```
    @Override
    public TypedValue getValueInternal(ExpressionState state) throws EvaluationException {
        // TODO possible optimization here if we cache the discovered type reference, but can we do that?
        String typeName = (String) this.children[0].getValueInternal(state).getValue();
        Assert.state(typeName != null, "No type name");
        if (!typeName.contains(".") && Character.isLowerCase(typeName.charAt(0))) {
            TypeCode tc = TypeCode.valueOf(typeName.toUpperCase());
            if (tc != TypeCode.OBJECT) {
                // It is a primitive type
                Class<?> clazz = makeArrayIfNecessary(tc.getType());
                this.exitTypeDescriptor = "Ljava/lang/Class";
                this.type = clazz;
                return new TypedValue(clazz);
            }
        }
        Class<?> clazz = state.findType(typeName);
        clazz = makeArrayIfNecessary(clazz);
        this.exitTypeDescriptor = "Ljava/lang/Class";
        this.type = clazz;
        return new TypedValue(clazz);
    }
```

I find a todo comments(`TODO possible optimization here if we cache the discovered type`) in the function, so there is no cache of type.It will exec the code`Class<?> clazz = state.findType(typeName)` when the function be called every time becaused of no cache of type.

Finally,it will call function`org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader#loadClass`, and there is a `synchronized` code block in the function, so many thread must block in there waiting to obtain the object's monitor lock.The souce of code of function `org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader#loadClass` is:

```
    @Override
    public Class<?> loadClass(String name, boolean resolve)
            throws ClassNotFoundException {
        synchronized (getClassLoadingLock(name)) {
            Class<?> result = findExistingLoadedClass(name);
            result = (result != null) ? result : doLoadClass(name);
            if (result == null) {
                throw new ClassNotFoundException(name);
            }
            return resolveIfNecessary(result, resolve);
        }
    }
```

Following is my hazelcast config and usage:

1.import the jar package in project pom file:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
            <artifactId>hazelcast</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
            <artifactId>hazelcast-spring</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

2.Config the hazelcast:

```
@Configuration
public class HazelcastConfiguration {

    @Value("${spring.profiles.active:Unknown}")
    private String activeProfile;
    @Value("${spring.application.name:Unknown}")
    private String applicationName;
    @Value("${hazelcast.syncIp}")
    private String syncIp;
    @Value("${hazelcast.manCenterIp:}")
    private String mngCenterIp;

    public HazelcastConfiguration() {
    }

    @Bean
    public Config hazelCastConfig() {
        Config config = new Config();
        config.getGroupConfig().setName(applicationName + "-" + activeProfile);
        if (StringUtils.hasText(mngCenterIp)) {
            config.getManagementCenterConfig().setEnabled(true);
            config.getManagementCenterConfig().setUrl(String.format("http://%s/hazelcast-mancenter", mngCenterIp));
        }
        JoinConfig join = config.getNetworkConfig().getJoin();
        join.getMulticastConfig()
                .setEnabled(false);
        join.getTcpIpConfig()
                .addMember(syncIp)
                .setEnabled(true);
        config.setInstanceName("hazelcast-instance")
                .addReplicatedMapConfig(
                        new ReplicatedMapConfig()
                                .setName(CacheConstants.CACHE_ALL_API_KEY_AND_SECRET)
                                .setQuorumName(CacheConstants.QUORUM_NAME)
                );
        return config;
    }
}
```

4.Used the hazelcast to cache data through spring cache annotation @Cacheable, like this:

```
    @Override
    @Cacheable(key = "T(String).valueOf(#channelPk)")
    public long findTvColumnPkByChanelPk(long channelPk) {
        ChannelTvColumnEntity entity = channelTvColumnMapper.findByChanelPk(channelPk);
        if (entity != null) {
            return entity.getTvColumnPk();
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: It definetly seems related to hazelcast cache you are using - can you add more information on how you have configured cache and how you are using it?

Comment: @somshivam Thanks, i have update the question description and add the information of hazelcast configuation & usage.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [release notes at Hazelcast](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/rn/index.html), there are several issues fixed around deadlock. 
You are lucky enough to be able to replicate the issue - so please upgrade to the latest version that you can upgrade to (3.12.7 is their last in 3.x series).  
 Hope that the issue is resolved - if not then get all details of  your Hazelcast config and open an issue here at their [GitHub](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues)

Comment: I try to update the hazelcast version from 3.11.2 to 3.12.7, but the problem still exist. What confuse me is that the thread stack trace has no hazelcast infomation.